# Hibernate/JPA polymorphie and generic type

Tags: hibernate, jpa, generics, polymorphism

I try to combine polymorphie and generic types in hibernate/JPA entities. Here are the example entities:

```
public class Cake {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Size(max = 36)
    @Column(length = 36)
    @UserInterface(showInForm = false, showInList = false)
    @Comment("Primary key")
    private String id;

    @Version
    @NotNull
    @UserInterface(showInForm = false, showInList = false)
    @Comment("Version column for optimistic locking")
    private int version;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(int version) {
        this.version = version;
    }
}
```

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Ingredient {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Size(max = 36)
    @Column(length = 36)
    @UserInterface(showInForm = false, showInList = false)
    @Comment("Primary key")
    private String id;

    @Version
    @NotNull
    @UserInterface(showInForm = false, showInList = false)
    @Comment("Version column for optimistic locking")
    private int version;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(int version) {
        this.version = version;
    }
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Vegetable extends Ingredient {
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Fruit extends Ingredient {
}
```

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class CakeIngredientLink<T extends Ingredient> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Size(max = 36)
    @Column(length = 36)
    @UserInterface(showInForm = false, showInList = false)
    @Comment("Primary key")
    private String id;

    @Version
    @NotNull
    @UserInterface(showInForm = false, showInList = false)
    @Comment("Version column for optimistic locking")
    private int version;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Cake cake;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private T ingredient;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(int version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public Cake getCake() {
        return cake;
    }

    public void setCake(Cake cake) {
        this.cake = cake;
    }

    public T getIngredient() {
        return ingredient;
    }

    public void setIngredient(T ingredient) {
        this.ingredient = ingredient;
    }
}
```

```
@Entity
public class CakeVegetable extends CakeIngredientLink<Vegetable> {
}
```

```
@Entity
public class CakeFruit extends CakeIngredientLink<Fruit> {
}
```

With `@MappedSuperclass` this design is possible. But with `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)` I get following exception:

```
Property de.cakeproject.domain.CakeIngredientLink.ingredient has an unbound type and no explicit target entity. Resolve this Generic usage issue or set an explicit target attribute (eg @OneToMany(target=) or use an explicit @Type
```

I want to use polymorphic queries to get all ingredients for a cake. This is not possible with `@MappedSuperclass`. What is a good way to achieve this problem?

Comment: JPA doesn't support queries to mappedSuperclasses, so while your model would have compiled - it isn't really possible. Generics are a pain. JPA usually requires the concrete type to determine what Entity a mapping needs to use and might not be able to see that T extends a valid Entity type (Ingredient) - try specifying targetEntity on all mappings using Generics, point them at the root entity in the inheritance graph (Ingredient) - just as the error tells you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have learned, and also tested, that it is possible to query a mappedSuperclass. The only thing you need to know is that the FQN of the entity is required in the query.

> Hibernate can also query interfaces or base classes that are not entities but are extended or implemented by entity classes.

[Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-inheritance#polymorphic-queries)

I'm not sure if this is specific to hibernate, but it's fine for me as a hibernate user.